# Make axes go through origin in Matlab 3D mesh plot

Tags: matlab, axis, mesh, axes

I am plotting a sphere in Matlab using the following code:

```
phi=linspace(0,pi,30);
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,30);
[phi,theta]=meshgrid(phi,theta);

x=sin(phi).*cos(theta);
y=sin(phi).*sin(theta);
z=cos(phi);

figure('Units', 'pixels', ...
 'Position', [200 200 433 433]);

colormap(copper)
mesh(x,y,z,'LineWidth',1.5)

xlabel('k_x','interpreter','tex');
ylabel('k_y','interpreter','tex');
zlabel('k_z','interpreter','tex');

set(gca,...
  'xtick'       , []        , ...
  'ytick'       , []        , ...
  'ztick'       , []        , ... 
  'LineWidth'   , 1.5         );

set(gcf,...
  'Color','w',...
  'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
```

As you can see, this simply plots a sphere on a white background, with no ticks, but with the x-, y- and z-axes.

Now, I want to have these axes to go through the origin of the sphere. That is, I want the axes to go through (0,0,0), and not like it is now, on the edges of the box. Also, I want to have the labels to be positioned at the positive end of the axis, if that is possible? Maybe an arrow at the end too? ... but that is not my main problem.

It feels like have searched the entire web for this simple problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Matlab R2014a or any other of its ealier versions, [Here](http://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30018-oaxes-central-axis-lines-through-an-origin) there is already an easy to use tool by John Barber for such implementation: